# Transforming models in order to use linear least squares estimations

Tags: self-study, data-transformation, least-squares

As a pre-exam question, I found a question asking to consider the following three models

$$
y = \beta_{0}(x_{1})^{\beta_{1}}(x_{2})^{\beta_{2}}\epsilon
$$
$$
y = \frac{1}{\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x + \epsilon}
$$

$$
y = \frac{1}{1+ e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x}\epsilon}
$$
and discuss how each of them might be transformed to use a linear least squares estimation.

To me the second and third models seem really simple, so simple that I may just be completely misunderstanding the purpose of the question. For the second one could simply take the inverse, and for the third one could take the inverse and then take the log. Is it as simple as stating that?

The first model, I am unsure what transformation to do.

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Some edits in response to comment)

For the first, note that you want to get from

$\beta_{0}\,\cdot x_{1}^{\beta_{1}}\,\cdot x_{2}^{\beta_{2}}\,\cdot\epsilon$

-- a product of terms -- to

$\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} x^*_{1}+ \beta_{2} x^*_{2}+ \epsilon$

-- a sum of terms (where $x^*$ may be some transformed variable)

Does that wish not suggest something?

Edit: As OP has now realized, the first is a matter of taking logs.

---

The third one isn't quite right.  There's an extra term you didn't deal with.

You still need the reciprocal, but otherwise your suggested change solves it.

Comment: Right right for the first one it's quite simply taking the log, my mistake. For the third one, is it sufficient to take the inverse, subtract $1$ from $y$ and _then_ take the log? Also thanks for letting me know about the tag correction, edited the question.

Comment: Not quite; now you have left out a step from your original solution.